# How do I make the navigation scale with the resizing of the window?

Tags: html, css

When I expand the window to the right, the welcome message as well as the background image will move to the right as well; however, the navigation below it does not move. What do I do so that they all move together?

```css
#flower-background-1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.fiftyflowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/iStock-659171982-1170x449.jpg");
  height: 300px;
  width: 900px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#welcome {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150px;
  background-color: indigo;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 170px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Test.css">
    <title>My Flower Shop</title>
</head>
<div id="flower-background-1"></div>
<div id="welcome">Welcome to My Flower Shop</div>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navigation">
            <nav id="Home">HOME</nav>
            <nav id="About Us">ABOUT US</nav>
            <nav id="Contact Us">CONTACT US</nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your header content into one responsive container, lets say a [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to CSS. Is there a code you can add to make the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 95%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #flower-background-1 {
            background-image: url("https://www.fiftyflowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/iStock-659171982-1170x449.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            max-height: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #welcome {
            font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
            font-size: 50px;
            border: 2px solid white;
            color: white;
            width: auto;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 150px;
            background-color: indigo;
        }
        nav {
            padding: 100px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
        nav a {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="flower-background-1"></div>
    <div id="welcome">Welcome to My Flower Shop</div>
    <header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a id="Home">HOME</a>
            <a id="About Us">ABOUT US</a>
            <a id="Contact Us">CONTACT US</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```